# Generate GUID in MySQL for existing Data?

Tags: mysql, random, guid

I've just imported a bunch of data to a MySQL table and I have a column "GUID" that I want to basically fill down all existing rows with new and unique random GUID's.

How do I do this in MySQL ?

I tried

```
UPDATE db.tablename
  SET columnID = UUID()
  where columnID is not null
```

And just get every field the same

Comment: are you really sure,they are same?I have tried ,most the characters are same,but there are a few differences in the generated uuid

Comment: Yes, I confirm, it's the same!

Comment: It works for me - the differences are minor, but are there. Quickest way to check is to add a UNIQUE constraint to the column.

Comment: Sorry to necro an old post here, but ```SET columnID = UUID()``` works - it's just if you're doing it over a large number of rows, the majority of the UUID characters will appear the same but there will be subtle differences.  +1 to PSU's answer

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the easiest way, but it works. The idea is to create a trigger that does all work for you, then, to execute a query that updates your table, and finally to drop this trigger:

```
delimiter //
create trigger beforeYourTableUpdate  BEFORE UPDATE on YourTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET new.guid_column := (SELECT UUID());
END
//
```

Then execute

```
UPDATE YourTable set guid_column = (SELECT UUID());
```

And `DROP TRIGGER beforeYourTableUpdate`;

**UPDATE**
Another solution that doesn't use triggers, but requires primary key or unique index :

```
UPDATE YourTable,
INNER JOIN (SELECT unique_col, UUID() as new_id FROM YourTable) new_data 
ON (new_data.unique_col = YourTable.unique_col)
SET guid_column = new_data.new_id
```

**UPDATE** once again:
It seems that your original query should also work (maybe you don't need `WHERE columnID is not null`, so all my fancy code is not needed.

Comment: yeah, it should work even in 5.0. But don't forget to drop the trigger!

Comment: yeah sure :) just wondering whether I need to check for duplicates after or whether this will create unique values for every row in the column ?

Comment: If `UUID` is implemented properly (and I believe it is), you should be able to create unique index without checking for duplicates.

Comment: I updated my answer with another approach which may also be useful.

Comment: your original code would work, just change columnId=UUID() to columnId=(SELECT UUID()). Worked great for me.  all the generated values are very close to being the same but each is unique.

Comment: UPDATE db.tablename
  SET columnID = UUID() works for me

Comment: Non trigger solution worked for me in laravel migrations where the original answer did not. I think it might have to do with how the transactions are executed.

Comment: Just a note that @a1ex07 might want to add to the answer: in 5.6 (I haven't tested others), if the columnId=(SELECT UUID()) is within a stored procedure, all the UUID values will be identical.

Comment: Is this trigger work properly on multi user envoirement?

Answer (score 163):

I had a need to add a guid primary key column in an existing table and populate it with unique GUID's and this update query with inner select worked for me:

```
UPDATE sri_issued_quiz SET quiz_id=(SELECT uuid());
```

So simple :-)

Comment: At first I thought this had inserted duplicate UUIDs because they all begin and end the same, but they are in fact slightly different.

Comment: @SamBarnum because `UUID` is generated based on the [machine and timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid). As a query that takes milliseconds to run, they have to be very very close indeed... but never the same... a good thing to assure you, is to add an `UNIQUE` index to that column.

Comment: The accepted answer seems an overkill comparing to this!

Comment: At least in mariadb (10.1.26) this does not seem to work, giving the same uuid for every record.

Comment: This generated the same UUID on every record for me, presumably because it's in a subquery and MySQL will execute the inner query first and use the same value for all rows. To solve it, remove the subquery: `UPDATE sri_issued_quiz SET quiz_id=uuid();`

Comment: @ChrisWhite, your pending edit should also revise the "inner select" part of the answer, or else it doesn't flow with your proposed code.

Answer (score 27):

The approved solution does create unique IDs but on first glance they look identical, only the first few characters differ.

If you want visibly different keys, try this:

```
update CityPopCountry set id = (select md5(UUID()));


MySQL [imran@lenovo] {world}> select city, id from CityPopCountry limit 10;
+------------------------+----------------------------------+
| city                   | id                               |
+------------------------+----------------------------------+
| A Coruña (La Coruña)   | c9f294a986a1a14f0fe68467769feec7 |
| Aachen                 | d6172223a472bdc5f25871427ba64e46 |
| Aalborg                | 8d11bc300f203eb9cb7da7cb9204aa8f |
| Aba                    | 98aeeec8aa81a4064113764864114a99 |
| Abadan                 | 7aafe6bfe44b338f99021cbd24096302 |
| Abaetetuba             | 9dd331c21b983c3a68d00ef6e5852bb5 |
| Abakan                 | e2206290ce91574bc26d0443ef50fc05 |
| Abbotsford             | 50ca17be25d1d5c2ac6760e179b7fd15 |
| Abeokuta               | ab026fa6238e2ab7ee0d76a1351f116f |
| Aberdeen               | d85eef763393862e5fe318ca652eb16d |
+------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

I'm using MySQL Server version:     5.5.40-0+wheezy1 (Debian)

Comment: In my case, i needed hyphens in the generated GUID. I used this: 
`SELECT INSERT(INSERT(INSERT(INSERT(MD5(UUID()), 9, 0, '-'), 14, 0, '-'), 19, 0, '-'), 24, 0, '-')`
Query is not very pretty but it does the job.

Comment: Isn't md5 less unique than UUIDs? I'd worry about collisions.

Comment: @Adam you are right. Even though a collision is rare, MD5 is not unique. I would not recommend using this method for the result the OP wants. Good discussions about it here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444321/how-are-hash-functions-like-md5-unique)

Answer (score 23):

```
select @i:=uuid();
update some_table set guid = (@i:=uuid());
```

Comment: perfect perfect perfect!! such small thing can have huge impact!!

Comment: Can confirm, simplest and only solution that works for me to set different UUID for many rows,

Answer (score 8):

Just a minor addition to make as I ended up with a weird result when trying to modify the UUIDs as they were generated.  I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11397626/14651) by [Rakesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1512332/rakesh-prajapati) to be the simplest that worked well, except in cases where you want to strip the dashes.

For reference:

```
UPDATE some_table SET some_field=(SELECT uuid());
```

This worked perfectly on its own.  But when I tried this:

```
UPDATE some_table SET some_field=(REPLACE((SELECT uuid()), '-', ''));
```

Then all the resulting values were the same (not subtly different - I quadruple checked with a `GROUP BY some_field` query).   Doesn't matter how I situated the parentheses, the same thing happens.

```
UPDATE some_table SET some_field=(REPLACE(SELECT uuid(), '-', ''));
```

It seems when surrounding the subquery to generate a UUID with REPLACE, it only runs the UUID query once, which probably makes perfect sense as an optimization to much smarter developers than I, but it didn't to me.

To resolve this, I just split it into two queries:

```
UPDATE some_table SET some_field=(SELECT uuid());
UPDATE some_table SET some_field=REPLACE(some_field, '-', '');
```

Simple solution, obviously, but hopefully this will save someone the time that I just lost.

Comment: Thanks, indeed you saved me some time. :)

Answer (score 7):

MYsql

```
UPDATE tablename   SET columnName = UUID()
```

oracle

```
UPDATE tablename   SET columnName = SYS_GUID();
```

SQLSERVER

```
UPDATE tablename   SET columnName = NEWID();;
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a simple typo. Didn't you mean "...where columnId *is* null"?

```
UPDATE db.tablename
  SET columnID = UUID()
  where columnID is null
```

Comment: I had the same thought when I read the question, but I don't think so: sounds like his columns contain values, but not UNIQUE values. The answers given long before your answer already show what is needed. There should not be a `WHERE` clause. And the values generated are very similar, so must look at them closely to see that they are indeed different.

Answer (score 4):

I faced mostly the same issue. 
Im my case uuid is stored as BINARY(16) and has NOT NULL UNIQUE constraints.
And i faced with the issue when the same UUID was generated for every row, and UNIQUE constraint does not allow this. So this query does not work:

`UNHEX(REPLACE(uuid(), '-', ''))`

But for me it worked, when i used such a query with nested inner select:

`UNHEX(REPLACE((SELECT uuid()), '-', ''))`

Then is produced unique result for every entry.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE db.tablename SET columnID = (SELECT UUID()) where columnID is not null
```

Comment: Please add some explanation on how your code works. Code without comments is not always easy to understand to other SO users

Comment: if u want to update uuid in existing data, run query as above with your condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
// UID Format: 30B9BE365FF011EA8F4C125FC56F0F50
UPDATE `events` SET `evt_uid` = (SELECT UPPER(REPLACE(@i:=UUID(),'-','')));

// UID Format: c915ec5a-5ff0-11ea-8f4c-125fc56f0f50
UPDATE `events` SET `evt_uid` = (SELECT UUID());

// UID Format: C915EC5A-5FF0-11EA-8F4C-125FC56F0F50
UPDATE `events` SET `evt_uid` = (SELECT UPPER(@i:=UUID()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(UUID(),'-',''), 1, 5), SUBSTRING(UPPER(REPLACE(UUID(),'-','')), 4, 5), SUBSTRING('@#$%(*&', FLOOR(RAND()*(1-8))+8, 1)) pass
```

I did this: `SELECT` five characters in lower case, five characters in upper case and one special character.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using mysql as sql_mode = "". After some testing, I decided that the problem was caused by this usage. When I tested on the default settings, I found that this problem was not there.
Note: Don't forget to refresh your connection after changing the mode.