# Shuffle database id

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I have a database with songs. Every song have an unique id. How I can generate a random unique value for every id in database?

Example:

```
id | song name    
1  | song1  
2  | song2  
3  | song3
```

After shuffle

```
id | song name    
45 | song1  
96 | song2  
10 | song3
```

Any idea?

Comment: how many songs in db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `FLOOR` and `RAND()` to get what you want.

If there are 1000 songs in your db.

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (1 - 1000 + 1)) + 1 AS ID, "song name"
FROM yourtable
```

If there are 7000 songs in your db.

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (1 - 7000 + 1)) + 1 AS ID, "song name"
FROM yourtable
```

Update..

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET id = FLOOR(RAND() * (1 - 1000 + 1)) + 1;
```

Comment: And what if `ID` is unique(make sense) and the rand will hit the same number twice(also make sense)

Comment: How do you avoid generating duplicate values for the id with this?

Answer (score 0):

Does the ID have to be an *integer*? If not you could think about using *GUIDS* . If this is a possibility for you, then you get further information for migrating your table here: 
[Generate GUID in MySQL for existing Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280789/generate-guid-in-mysql-for-existing-data)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT  @nr:=@nr+1 AS nr, tmp.* 
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM yourTable ORDER BY rand()
  ) AS tmp
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @nr:=0 ) AS parameter
```