# Duplicate entry Exception while generating UUID in Liquibase changeset

Tags: mysql, uuid, liquibase, unique-constraint

I'm using a Liquibase changeset to update `null` values of the `customId` column. The sql is a modified version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11397626/184792).

The problem is that it seems to use the same UUID for all rows. My changeset looks like this:

```
<changeSet id="v3.0.3" author="msp" runAlways="false">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">select count(*) from FOOBAR where customId is null</sqlCheck>
        </not>
    </preConditions>

    <sql>update FOOBAR set customId = concat('cu:', (select uuid())) where customId is null</sql>
</changeSet>
```

Note that if I'm running this slightly modified version of the query (adding a limit of 2) in the MySQL console, then it works:

`update FOOBAR set customId = concat('cu:', (select uuid())) where customId is null limit 2`

But if I try to run the very same query (including the limit) with liquibase, I get the following Exception:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set changelog/db.changelog-v3.0.3.xml::v3.0.3::msp:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL update FOOBAR set customId = concat('cu:', (select uuid())) where customId is null limit 2: Duplicate entry 'cu:cde325da-f71f-11e5-95f8-d15a50829a7d' for key 'customId'
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:554)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:43)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:70)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:195)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:174)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:330)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL update FOOBAR set customId = concat('cu:', (select uuid())) where customId is null limit 2: Duplicate entry 'cu:cde325da-f71f-11e5-95f8-d15a50829a7d' for key 'customId'
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:62)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:122)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1206)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1189)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:518)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'cu:cde325da-f71f-11e5-95f8-d15a50829a7d' for key 'customId'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1039)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2627)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:841)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:681)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.execute(NewProxyStatement.java:1006)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:310)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    ... 89 more
```

Note that there's of course a `UNIQUE` constraint on `customId` - but shouldn't `select uuid()` (also tried `uuid()` without select) generate a unique value, even when using Liquibase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved with a small workaround. I split the update into two queries:

```
<changeSet id="v3.0.3" author="msp" runAlways="false">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">select count(*) from FOOBAR where customId is null</sqlCheck>
        </not>
    </preConditions>

    <sql>update FOOBAR set customId = (select uuid())) where customId is null</sql>
    <sql>update FOOBAR set customId = concat('cu:', customId) where length(customId) = 36
</changeSet>
```

This of course only works for my case where I can be sure that all rows of the first query can be identified by `length(customId) = 36`.