# SQL Server : Taking Numerical Characters and Hashing them under with a max length of 20 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hash

Hello I was trying to find a good way to hash a set of numerical numbers which its output would be under 20 characters that are positive and unique. Any one have any suggestions?

Comment: A numeric output hash? how big a set of numbers in what range? stuff them in a table and use an identity?

Comment: I'm not aware that you can hash to a specific data size ***and*** guarnatee uniqueness.  Do you have examples of what you are trying to here, and why?  We may be able to offer alternative approaches, and/or close-enough approaches.  For example, if you're hashing to speed up a search, indexes already do that.  If you want to hash two identical values to generate a unique identifier for each, IDENTITY columns will do something like that...

Comment: @Dems The asker most likely means "unique enough": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444321/how-are-hash-functions-like-md5-unique

Comment: @Dems, *no* hash can guarantee uniqueness. But crypto hash algorithms such as SHA1 do a good job of reducing the collision probability to an accepably low level. If you then take just a part of that hash (just like Git or Mercurial do for the "friendly" changeset IDs) the collision probability is still very low, at an acceptable level for most applications.

Comment: @Lucero - What about hashing to an output space that is dimensionally larger than the input space?  If you have n inputs, with n^2 technically possible output hash values, is it possible to codify the hashing function to guarantee no collisions?

Comment: @Dems, if the output is always larger than the input then you don't need hashing really (except if you're after an even distribution for usage in algorithms such as hash tables - but that's a different story) - just take the binary data as the hash and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

For hashing in general, I'd use the [`HASHBYTES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) function. You can then convert the binary data to a string and just pick the first 20 characters, that should still be unique enough.

To get around `HASHBYTES` limitations (8000 bytes for instance), you can incrementally hash, e.g. for each value concat the previous hash with the value to be added and hash that again. This will make it unique with order etc. and unless you append close to 8000 bytes in one value it will not cause data truncation for the hashing.

Comment: the string to be hashed is at max 8-9 characters. Thank you all for your answers