# String to number generator

Tags: c#, hash

I m looking for a way to convert a string to a unique Id.

Ideas invited for an algorithm that comes up with a unique number for each string sent to it.

I tried to use hash code but then realized that two strings could have the same hash code.

How do I generate a unique code for each string as input and two same strings should generate me the same id at all times.

Comment: I would need the same string to generate the same id each and every time . I don't think guid fits here.

Comment: @GutterStink - You have already answered your own question. Either that or you are asking for something impossible. A hash will always generate the same code for two identical strings. If you want two string sent "differently" to generate unique ID's but also have them continue to generate the same ID every time that is impossible without additional meta data.

Comment: Start over with a new question with all your requirements ( e.g. size of the unique id - is it integral or a string, etc. )

Comment: Two strings have a 1:2^32 chance of having the same hash code (assuming `string.GetHashCode` is "good").  Are you sure you can't live with that?

Comment: Do you want to re-create a string using the number? If yes then maybe take a look on some data compression algorithms (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78_(algorithms) ) ?

Answer (score 3):

Can you have characters in your "unique ID"? If so, this should work ;-)

```
public string MakeUnique(string s)
{
    return s;
}
```

All ID's will be unique to the value provided. The same string, will produce the exact same ID. That's what you wanted right?

---

If it's an integer result you want, how about converting each character to an int...

```
public int MakeUnique(string s)
{
    string result = "";

    foreach(var c in s)
    {
        result += ((int)c).ToString();
    }

    return Int.Parse(result);
}
```

**WARNING**: This will break if the string is [too big](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Simply append or prepend a guid:

```
string foo = "MyString";

//Simply throw it on the end
string uniqueString = foo + Guid.NewGuid();

//Prepend with underscore
string uniqueString = String.Format("{0}_{1}", foo, Guid.NewGuid());

//Append with underscore
string uniqueString = String.Format("{0}_{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), foo);
```

**Edit (new requirement)**

You have not provided enough information for me to post a great answer to this question. For example, environment (web, winforms, etc.) would be beneficial.

To point you in the right direction...

If the unique string that is returned needs to be the same when you pass in a string a second time, you could maintain a history of generated strings and check it each time generation is requested.

Truthfully, there are lots of ways to skin this cat...

Comment: I would need to make sure that the same guid is generated when I pass the same string the next time...

Comment: @GutterStink, that requirement certainly changes things, but this is still a viable method. Remember, it's important to really think through your requirements before your post your question so you don't require those who answer to backtrack.

Comment: My apologies about that. I shall keep that in mind the next time.

Answer (score 1):

If the original string is sensitive, similar to [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/), you could encrypt the string with [MD5 encryption](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/)

As you have stated, and [@Austin Salonen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436935/string-to-number-generator/15437439#comment21836024_15436935) commented, they're not 100% unique, but the risk is low:

[How are hash functions like MD5 unique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444321/how-are-hash-functions-like-md5-unique)

Comment: @ReacherGilt: Yes it is, it's "one way encryption". I would post a link that details this, but yours already does the job. You should try reading your own links before you use them to try and prove someone wrong. I know it's not normally what you would call encryption, but still

Comment: @ReacherGilt You've just quoted "MD5 is not encryption like you may think" and "While MD5 is a form of one way encryption". That's 2 references to MD5 being a form of encryption.

Comment: @ReacherGilt: Sticking with your link... "Encryption is the transformation of information with an algorithm." (this is what an MD5 does). And to cement the point, data encrypted with an MD5 algorithm can also be decrypted - although I stress the impracticalities of this, but it is possible

Comment: @ReacherGilt This is becoming irrelevant. The OP has never asked for the ability to convert the outputted result back into the original string. Furthmore: `In a technical, computer science sense you are both absolutely correct.`. This is StackOverflow, we are talking in the context of technical/computer science.

Answer (score 0):

A string can be fairly long and consists of charactes, which are 16-bit values. The number of possible strings is huge (much more than the range of integer or Guid). So you can't have a function that "just" translates a string into some guaranteed unique code, without some help.

You could use a database table: lookup your string in the table. If it's not there, insert it, generating a new (sequential) unique id. If it's there, use that id. The number of possible strings is huge, the number of strings you encounter, probably not.