# Youtube-Like IDs (UrL) With Php and MysQL

Tags: php, mysql, video

I have one question for the video url.

I am trying to make a video upload. so this is my basic video upload code :

```
<?php

include_once '../includes.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($temp,"uploaded/".$name);
    $url = "http://localhost:8888/videouploadandplayback/uploaded/$name";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `video` VALUE ('','$name','$url')");
}

?>
```

in this code `$url` section is video url.

and this is my `watch.php` code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `video` WHERE id='$id'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $url = $row['url'];
    }

    echo "You are watching ".$name."<br />";
    echo "<video id='my_video_1' class='video-js vjs-default-skin' 
      controls preload='none' width='640px' height='267px' data-setup='{}'>
    <source src='$url' type='video/mp4' />
  </video>";
}
else
{
    echo "Error!";
}

?>
```

in this code `<source src='$url' type='video/mp4' />` section shows like this :

```
<source src="http://localhost:8888/videouploadandplayback/uploaded/158382524199979_46659.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

but i want to change it for example like this :

```
<source src="http://localhost:8888/videouploadandplayback/uploaded/x5Wa88Bq" type="video/mp4">
```

How do I make a URL (Like Youtube)in this way?

Comment: log the uploaded filename to a db and create a unique has for it?

Comment: @RamRaider How can I do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright, first of all, your code you're using there is vulnerable.(`$_GET['id']` part) You should check out [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [sanitizing your code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php) The most important thing is to stay safe.

I'd start with making a unique name for your file first (cool looking, youtube style if that's what you're looking for.)

You can solve this in any way you like, here's my very simplistic example.

```
//if no errors
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];//Our name 
$temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //Get the extension before we make any changes.

$name =md5($name.microtime());//md5 of our name and microtime, this makes sure the encryption is random most of the time, because microtime is always changing.
$name = substr($name, 0,8); //Cutting off the part we don't need

move_uploaded_file($temp,"uploaded/".$name.'.'.$ext); //Storing out file
```

Now, lets add this to a database. -->

```
+----+----------+------+
| id |   name   | ext  |
+----+----------+------+
| x  | x5Wa88Bq | .mp4 |
+----+----------+------+
```

I made this database assuming you will always have a same path to your uploads, if not then you will have to go with a different solution.

```
 //?Selecting from database by id, if no errors     $name = $row['name'];

 echo "You are watching ".$name."<br />";
 echo "<video id='my_video_1' class='video-js vjs-default-skin' 
 controls preload='none' width='640px' height='267px' data-setup='{}'>
 <source src='load.php?v=$name' type='video/mp4' />   </video>";
```

Now we should create a load.php file, which will actually point somewhere to our video.

load.php ->

```
$v = $_GET['v']; //Sanitise first, don't use like this.

//Compare with database, if true get name and extension
$name = $row['name'];
$ext = $row['ext'];
$url = 'http://localhost:8888/videouploadandplayback/uploaded/';


if(!empty($v)){
    header("location:"$url.$name.$ext."");  
}
```

Our load.php now checks if there is a video with a specific name  (ex. x5Wa88Bq), since that file exists it points it to the correct directory. The code that handles the video realises that `load.php?v=$name` points to a video (or not) and plays it (doesn't).

Now if you want to do more 'styling', you can check out [.htaccess guides](http://www.htaccesstools.com/). It will help you out with rewriting your URL's. And hopefully then you could do

```
<source src='$name' type='video/mp4' />
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your best reply. I try it but when i posted video  video name looks like this => `a7a34c9a.mp4`  in database table

Comment: Ah, the problem was I concatenated $name and $ext before actually adding it to the 'database'. You can check out the code again, i've edited it. (The first code block)

Comment: i am not using load page i am using video.php page this page shows all the video link.

Comment: Not really following you right now. I've changed the code so it won't add .mp4 into the database anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your reply dear. Can you tell me i am not using load.php page i have video.php page this page have all the video link. Click the link then open video page.how can i do this page. This is my last question from you :) Thank you so much

Comment: my video.php page code is this :

`<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `video`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{$id = $row['id'];
 $name = $row['name'];echo "<a href='watch.php?id=$name'>$name</a><br />";}?>`

Comment: Your href should be watch.php?id=$id

Comment: can you tell me watch.php <source src='watch.php?id=$name' type='video/mp4' />  is true. Because video not showing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57056/discussion-between-ecowebtr-and-sidetik).

Comment: Cutting of a md5-hash just to get some shorter "id" is bad. Even using a full-md5-hash as id is bad. Hashes are NO ids. An id needs to be unique. Hashes aren't.

Comment: While this is true, I wanted to give him the basic idea. Anyway, [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444321/how-are-hash-functions-like-md5-unique).

Answer (score 3):

Just generate your database-entry using an auto-increment id to *ensure* unique values per file uploaded.

Then, you could simple convert the (decimal) id to a string with another base - and you have a *youtoube-like-id*:

```
$youtubeLikeId = base_convert($actual_id, 10, 35);
```

example values:

```
$youtubeLikeId = base_convert(21122544, 10, 35); //returns e2mv9
```

to get the original (surogate) id back, just reverse the base conversion:

```
$actual_id = base_convert("e2mv9", 35,10); //returns 21122544
```

Sidenode: Youtube uses an enhanced conversion by also using capital-letters.